# Bash script to test if a file contains multiple strings otherwise add missing string?

Tags: linux, bash, grep, printf

I'm attempting to make a post-install script for Ubuntu 13.04 so that when run it will automatically install my desired programs and apply my desired settings such as create aliases so that apt-get=apt-fast, wget=aria2c and sudo="sudo ". At the beginning of the script I have it set to check for the alias list and expand it for use within the script if it exists so that the aliases are used throughout the script versus the original commands.

What I wish for the script to do is test does ~/bash_aliases exist, if so then look for string1, string2, string3. If file exists and all strings found then echo Aliases already in place otherwise add the missing strings or create the file if it doesn't exist containing all aliases. After having searched for a while I have a basic layout, but my problem is it's searching as OR not AND. Once it finds any of the strings it says ok they are there and doesn't add the missing strings.

Here is what I have so far:

```
if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    if grep -q "# Additional Alias Definitions" "alias apt-get='apt-fast'" "alias wget='aria2c'" "alias sudo='sudo '" ~/.bash_aliases; then
        echo 'Aliases already in place.'
    else
        printf "%s\n" "# Additional Alias Definitions" "alias apt-get='apt-fast'" "alias wget='aria2c'" "alias sudo='sudo '" >> ~/.bash_aliases
    fi
else
        printf "%s\n" "# Additional Alias Definitions" "alias apt-get='apt-fast'" "alias wget='aria2c'" "alias sudo='sudo '" >> ~/.bash_aliases
fi
```

How do I get it to work how I desire?

Edit: I managed to get it to work, not exactly done the way I wanted but works nonetheless... http://paste.progval.net/show/582/

Answer (score 1):

I think you are taking the wrong approach here: you try to alter files provided by other packages. Such thing is always done in good intentions, but nevertheless it often fails, since no one can predict how those other packages will change.

Instead a modular concept has proved more stable, which adds separate files for each package installed and references those files from a central place. The first distribution to consequently follow this strategy was openSUSE some years ago, these days most other distributions have adapted that strategy or are switching over to it. The only exception probably are minimalistic distributions being limited in storage place and/or computation capacity. For all other situations the additional file to be opened and processed is an accepted penalty which is justified by a more stable and transparent installation or setup scheme.

Please note: your approach certainly is possible, I just describe an alternative one which has proven more stable, convenient and transparent.

Define a separate file holding your alias definitions. Put that file into a separate package (rpm or deb) as `/etc/profile.d/local-alias` or the like, the exact path obviously depending on the distribution you use. That package is to be installed into any system where those definitions are required. This makes the installation a transparent and above all a cleanly revertable process. The origin of the additional definitions is well documented inside the package management.

The setup routines on modern systems scan the `profile.d` folder and will execute any script installed in there. This processing is typically defined in a file like `/etc/profile`, have a look for the details of your distribution. This mechanism enables packages to drop their own requirements and definitions inside the system without each having to alter files installed by other packages, a process which can never work out stable in the long run with thousands of packages getting installed and removed, all bringing their own requirements and dependencies. Other examples where this strategy is typically applied are modules for the http server getting installed on an optional base or specific shell environments which typically require their own set of definition files.

Note that the names and paths I specified are openSUSE specific. I have little experience with Ubuntu but you will probably find their implementation of this approach easily.

Comment: I had thought about taking that approach as well, but then having to check for the separate alias lists and then expand them in the script in order for it to run the desired program within the script seemed like it would be more difficult. And perhaps my original post was still a little vague. I am trying to make a post-install script so that I can run the script and have it automatically add my desired programs and settings without having to do it all manually. I will edit my original post to add that bit of information.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see why that clean approach should be more difficult or require more manual actions. If 'post-install' means after having installed some software to prepare the usage of that software then add the additional definition file described above as part of the software  package you install. You do not have to do anything manually, the system already automatically processes such scripts dropped at the right places reserved for such scripts.

Comment: Meaning, from a clean install of Ubuntu 13.04 that I can run the script and have it first install aria2c and apt-fast then check for the ~/bash_aliases and expand the alias list for use throughout the remainder of the script to then download and install all of my desired programs, as well as apply my desired settings so that I can go from a clean install to a complete setup just by running the script. But, my issues lies that once it checks the ~/bash_alias file if it finds even one of the specified entries it will not add the other required entries for my script to function properly.

Comment: So this 'script' will run only once to install some software and that's it? And your only problem is to make sure your alias definitions are applied? Then why do you have to process the existing alias definitions at all? Just define your aliases, they will replace any existing aliases defined when starting the shell which executes your script and they will be inherited down to all processes you start from your script.

Comment: After running the script I want for the aliases to remain in place in the ~/bash_aliases file so that in the future whenever I run apt-get it is processed as apt-fast instead automatically. Where as it was my understanding that if I just defined them in the script it would only apply while the script is running. I want it to process the existing so that if I run the script on an install that already has a defined alias list it can check to see if those aliases are in place and if not add them so it functions as desired throughout the script as well as afterwards.

Comment: Ok, that is something different. So in the end this is not a oneshot process, but we are back at a permanent setup again. That is nothing you should do by your approach, since it means you modify the existing software in a "wild" manner. This is neither transparent not reversable. This is what the package management is for. Do not make a "wild" install of definitions, there are good reasons why this approach is not considered a good practice any more. Your decision, but if you want to install something in a permanent manner (which is what you describe), then do it the clean way, I'd say.

Comment: I'm unsure what you mean by modifying the existing software in a 'wild' manner. Granted, I am inexperienced with linux. But, I don't see how creating an alias list to contain my desired aliases to use in bash would be harmful. All of the bash scripting guides that I have read have suggested to not edit the .bashrc file to add aliases instead create a personal alias list which is what i'm attempting to do via the script. The alias file is referenced in the .bashrc to also load my desired aliases. All I really need to know is how to check if all lines are present otherwise add the missing lines?